# C# Zipping library that allows renaming of files in zip package (not DotNetZip)

Tags: c#, compression, zip, libraries

I have had reliability issues with compressing large files (1GB+, using UseZip64WhenSaving = AsNecessary) with DotNetZip (took too long, intermittent failure) and am now looking for a different compression library.

One of the hard requirements I have is that the library allows the renaming of files within the package. The files are being downloaded and have a strict naming convention that differs to mine (which cannot be changed either). This rules out SharpZipLib as that doesn't provide the feature I require.

Does anybody have any reliable suggestions/solutions for this dilemma?

Equally, if somebody has suggestions for serving large collections of media files (rarely more than 10GB) in a convenient method other than zipping, I'm all ears! :)

Answer (score 0):

7zip has a sdk, please have a look :

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html‎